# How to Modify default separator for CTAGS generated tag file

Tags: c++, ctags, exuberant-ctags

The default separator is tab character which is \t. However, if there are comments in a line of code being analyzed it messes up the format of the generated tag file. How to Modify default separator for CTAGS generated tag file?

Comment: And your question is? I don't spot a question mark.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may like xformat feature of Universal-ctags. With the feature you can define your own format of output.

```
[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% cat input.c

#define ZERO 0
int main(void)
{
    return ZERO;
}
[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% ./ctags -x --_xformat='(N, K, L) = ("%{name}", "%{kind}", %{line})' input.c

(N, K, L) = ("ZERO", "macro", 1)
(N, K, L) = ("main", "function", 2)
```

http://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/news.html#customizing-xref-output may give you more hints.